# update a mysql table by joining on four columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update a table of about 2.5 million transactions by adding a budget_id column that's stored in a separate table. Where four fields match, I want to set the budget_id column in the transactions table equal to the budget_id field in the budget table:

```
update transactions t 
join budget b on t.field_1 = b.field_1
and t.field_2 = b.field_2
and t.field_3 = b.field_3
and t.field_4 = b.field_4
set t.budget_id = b.budget_id;
```

There are about 6,900 rows in the budget table, each with a unique budget_id. So I am trying to match these 6,900 rows to the 2.5 million rows in my transactions table by joining on four columns. Every time I run this query I lose my connection. Each column is indexed in both tables and I am using a google cloud instance with 8 GB RAM. My innodb_buffer_pool_size is 6 GB. Would really appreciate it if someone can tell me why this is happening or how I can do this more efficiently so that it won't crash. Thanks very much.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you perform the above as a select statement? I.E. replace the word "update" with "select * from" and remove the last line. Does it execute in a timely fashion? If it doesn't, which I think it won't, you could perform an explain and see what's taking the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Each column is indexed".  Actually, you want a *composite* index.  The best for this query would be:

```
create idx_budget_field1_field2_field3_field4_budget_id
    on budget(field_1, field_2, field_3, field_4, budget_id);
```